# Django and PostgreSQL latest and greatest versions

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I heard about lots of compatibility issues with PostgreSQL and Django + psycopg2.

What would be the recommended latest and greatest versions that are **fully compatible** for a new Django project starting from scratch?

Comment: I don't know about those compatibility issues, but where I work we're using PostgreSQL 9.0.x and Django 1.3 (using psycopg2) without any problems.

Comment: @DaniloBargen, thanks. What about PostgreSQL 9.1.x?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. You can see backward compatibility issues here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#Backward_compatibility_issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is not critical: it only affects database creation during tests: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16250 There should be no other problem between psycopg and django.

The problem can be avoided using psycopg 2.4.1, but there have been several bug fixes since then, so I'd rather apply some simple patch to django to make the two play well together.

BTW I wonder when will they release django 1.3.2: the bug is been there for 6 months now...

Comment: Not sure this bug will be backported to 1.3.X. Might have to wait for 1.4.